# segmentation fault (core dumped) in C program to make histogram

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a program that shows a histogram. I keep getting segmentation fault (core dumped) each time I run it. I am reading in a file with numbers in it and trying to find the occurrences of each number and to print a histogram from it. I have looked all over but can not seem to find why this is happening. Please tell me why.

**INPUT random.txt**

```
1405413042132140413140
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
0 ****
1 ******
2 ** 
3 ***
4 ******
5 *
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int n = 1001; 
    int a[n];
    int opt;

    FILE *f;
    if(argc == 5){
        f = fopen(argv[5], "r");
    }
    else if(argc == 4){
        f = fopen(argv[4], "r");
    }
    else if(argc == 3){
        f = fopen(argv[3], "r");
    }
    else if(argc == 2){
        f = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    }
    else if(argc == 1){
        f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    }
    else if(f == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: File Not Found\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your input? When are you getting the segfault? Can you reduce it to [mcve]?

Comment: Then you should fire up a debugger to find the line where the segfault is. If possible, remove `argc` and `argv` completely by hard coding the values.

Comment: `if(f == NULL)` should not be in `else` -- it won't run if any of the other `if/else if` blocks run.

Comment: `if(argc == 5){
        f = fopen(argv[5], "r");
    }` is invalid. Indexes start at 0, so when `argc == 5`, the last argument is `argv[4]`.

Comment: @klutt It looks to me like the bug is in the `argv` processing, so the problem would go away if he did that.

Comment: @Barmar Well, in that case OP can remove the histogram function. In either case, it's not  a [mre] :)

Comment: @klutt It's hard to remove unnecessary code if you don't know what part of the code has the problem

Comment: @Barmar Which is why I told OP to use a debugger to find which line that causes the segfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since array indexes start at `0`, the last argument in `argv` is `argv[argc-1]`. Your code is trying to use `argv[argc]` as the filename, but this element always contains a null pointer, which is causing the segmentation fault when you call `fopen()`.

You should also notice the pattern in all your `if` statements, which allows you to combine them all into a single line.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int n = 1001; 
    int a[n];
    int opt;
    struct options opts = {60, '*', 3, '\n'};
    while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "s:m:c:w:n") != -1)){
        switch(opt){
        case 's':
            opts.scale = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'm':
            opts.c = optarg[0];
            break;
        case 'w':
            opts.width = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'n':
            opts.bars = 0;
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Valid options are s,m,c,w,n\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("ERROR: filename is required\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[argc-1], "r");
    if (f == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: File Not Found\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    count(f, a, n);
    max(n, a);
    histogram(n, a, &opts);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, you put it in easier terms where I can understand. I was trying to use a debugger and got a headache.